# Array not null, but on database saved as NULL (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have array data

```
 $data = [
  "_token" =>   "ERtVJwSXqfcyPJ452patZVmNnH75BZLDroKR1OaA"  
  "name" => "Ardy Febriansyah" 
  "username" => "ardyfeb2402"
  "email" => "ardyfeb02@gmail.c" 
  "password" => "ardyfeb2402"
  "password_confirm" => "ardyfeb2402"
 ]
```

And i save

```
User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' =>  Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
```

But `$data['username']` stored as null to database

I have already check `$data['username']`the result isn`ardyfeb2402`

Comment: Is the casing the same? Is your column username and not, eg userName?

Comment: Is username in the $fillable array on your User model?

Comment: Lack of research...

Comment: Thanks all, solved by add username to $fillable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `username` field to the `$fillable` array on the model.

You need this because you do mass assignment (passing an array into the create function) and by default, Eloquent will protect columns that are not listed for mass assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `<input type="text" name="username">`

and also have a look at your Model `$fillable = ['username']` add `username` and other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick reminder, you can just define protected $guarded = [] ( empty array ), and you dont have to add specified columns in $guarded. But most of the cases, you want to keep some atributes guarded.

Answer (score 0):

Your $fillable property on the User model does not contain 'username' and therefore I won't be added when you use a static method.In this case User::create([]);

If you want to keep the model as it is,then you can try

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = $data['name'];
$user->username = $data['username'];
$user->save();
```

of just simply update protected $fillable = ['name','email','username'];

or for just local development you can set $guarded property to null on your User model.

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

**$guard and $guarded** are not the same.
should not use $guarded = [] in production.